# Cumulative multiplication from behind using groupby()

Tags: pandas

I tried to make a cumulative multiplication of column rate from the back grouping by id.

`df.groupby(['id'])['rate'].apply(lambda x: x * x.shift(-1))`

**Initial Dataframe**

```
data = {'id': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300], 
        'year':  [2010, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2010, 2012, 2008],
        'rate':  [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1],
        'tval': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 90, 90, 100]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**More details**

```
For example id=100
0.1 x 0.1 x 0.1 x 0.2 x 0.1
0.1 x 0.1 x 0.1 x 0.2
0.1 x 0.1 x 0.1
0.1 x 0.1
0.1
```

**Goal**

[image]

Comment: `df[::-1].groupby('id').rate.cumprod()[::-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['result'] = (df.groupby('id').rate
                  .transform(lambda x: x[::-1].cumprod()[::-1])
               )
```

Output:

```
    id  year  rate  tval   result
0  100  2010   0.1    10  0.00002
1  100  2013   0.2    10  0.00020
2  100  2014   0.1    10  0.00100
3  100  2015   0.1    10  0.01000
4  100  2016   0.1    10  0.10000
5  200  2010   0.1    90  0.02000
6  200  2012   0.2    90  0.20000
7  300  2008   0.1   100  0.10000
```

Comment: I think this may be faster:  `df[::-1].groupby('id').rate.cumprod()[::-1]`